# What is the preferred way to handle this in java

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public interface X {
...
}

public class A implements X {
...
}

public class B implements X {
...
}
```

Now let's say I have a method somewhere that takes an object of type X, and must handle each implementation of X differently. The naïve approach is:

```
public void doSomething(X x) {
  if(x instanceof A)
    doSomethingA((A) x);
  else if(x instanceof B)
    doSomethingB((B) x);
}
```

...but this seems particularly ugly and not polymorphic. What is the clean way of handling such a situation in general?

EDIT: Sure, it would be easy if I could push the implementation of doSomething() to classes A and B, but what about in situations where that doesn't make sense? i.e. doSomething() is defined on a class C and the implementation is highly dependent on C's internal state.

Comment: +1 for a subtle question that most people scan read and answer incorrectly.

Comment: I would try to redesign it then.BTW, do we need the 'general' doSomething(X x) method?

Comment: For example, can we simply pass required part of C's state to A's and B's implementations? Or split C.doSomethingA/B somehow to a few parts to have a common one in C, and different ones - in A and B respectively?

Comment: Can you share more information about what you're actually doing in these methods? It certainly feels like a redesign is necessary, but as the details are so abstract at the moment it's difficult to advise.

Comment: I've run into it in a few different situations. That's why I'm looking for a general solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy:

```
public interface X {
  int doSomething();
}

public class A implements X {
  public int doSomething() {
    // implementation in A
  }  
}

public class B implements X {
  public int doSomething() {
    // implementation in B
  }  

}
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, seems here we have some algorithm in C which dependants on C's state as well as on A/B differences. Then I would try to split that algorithm so that C class has only a common implementation for both A and B, and A-/B-dependent parts should go to an appropriate class as a particular implementation of the same method which is invoked in C. If possible, C's state can partially be passed to A's and B's doSomething

Comment: This is not the solution he wants to pass variables not call methods.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why it's necessary to pass the same object to the method. Moreover, there is 'this' inside doSomething, anyway

Comment: Since I haven't given any context, it may seem easy, but in practice it may not be so easy. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, got it. Asked some questions in comments to the question

Answer (score 4):

You should push the implementation of `doSomethingA` to class `A` and `doSomethingB` to `classB`, define `doSomething` in the interface `X` and just call `x.doSomething()` (something in the lines of [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)).

Considering the latest edit on the question about the dependency of the processing on `X` being of type `A` or `B`, `instanceof` operator certainly shouldn't be used because it establishes a hard-dependency on the underlying implementation class and the code would fail miserably when `X x` passed to `C.doSomething()` is a decorated instance.

AFAIK, the implementation of `C.doSomething()` will boil down to a point where you would have to use the information from either `A` or `B` and the steps run at the point should be abstracted into methods in `A` and `B`, declared in interface `X`. This will ensure that any new implementations of `X` also implement this method that `C` relies on, thereby making the code better maintainable. HTH.

Comment: @AmitD, as can be seen from the question, the edit came after the responses. Please see the edit to my response, commenting on the new requirement in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this would the [visitor pattern](http://java-x.blogspot.com.es/2007/01/implementing-visitor-pattern-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would implement an interface rather then extend :) and my first tought would be this way

```
  class Parent {
      public Parent() {

      }
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
      public Child() {
        super();
      }
    }

    public class MainClass {
      public static void main(String[] a) {

        Child child = new Child();
        if (child instanceof Parent) {
          System.out.println("true");
        }

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public interface X {
     doSomeThing();
    }

public class A implement X {
  doSomeThing(){}
}

public class B implement X {
   doSomeThing() {}
}
```

Now you can use

```
  X a = new A();
  a.doSomeThing();
```

Comment: This is not the solution he wants to pass variables not call methods.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move do something() into the interface X? Then just call x.do something() without needing to cast or use instance of.

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a design problem.
If A and B implementations of doSomething() depends heavily on a C object state, you could pass it as an argument : x.doSomething(C c)

---

Create doSomething() in interface X :

```
public interface X {
   doSomething(C c);
}

public class A extends X {
   doSomething(C c) {
    ...
   }
}

public class B extends X {
   doSomething(C c) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Then, your initial method becomes :

```
public void doSomething(X x) {
  x.doSomething(C c);
}
```